# Best way to add all elements in an int array into a priority queue in Java

Tags: java

I have an int array and I need to create a priority queue from it.

currently I have:

```
int[] costs=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq=new PriorityQueue<>();
        
for(int cost:costs){
    pq.add(cost);
}
```

Is there any other choice that might be better?

Comment: what _exactly_ is bothering you with your current implementation? that looks just fine to me. And no, `pq.addAll(Arrays.asList(costs))` is not by any means any better then you already have.

Comment: @Eugene: `Arrays.asList​(T... a)` wouldn't work anyway, since generic type argument `T` cannot be the *primitive* type `int`.

Comment: @Andreas right, I assumed that since the OP is asking such a low level question (I again assume he cares about the overhead here), this would have been obvious

Comment: @Eugene Since OP is asking such a "low level" (read "simple") question, we should assume that OP knows nothing about the limitations (quirks) of generics.

Comment: Convert the array to a binary heap with an implementation of heapsort: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/building-heap-from-array/ then use that as the base for your priority queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one statement using Java 8 Stream. Whether that is "better" is a matter of opinion.

For comparison, here they are side-by-side:

```java
int[] costs = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};

// Java 5.0 or later
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
for (int cost : costs)
    pq.add(cost);

// Java 8 or later
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = Arrays.stream(costs).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(PriorityQueue::new));
```

If `costs` had been an `Integer[]`, it would be different:

```java
Integer[] costs = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};

PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Arrays.asList(costs));
```